# Export environment variable Mac

Tags: macos, environment-variables, spring-roo

I am starting with spring-roo, so I downloaded it and now I'm trying to export the variable.
To get it, I tried:

> PATH=$PATH:/Users/myUsr/spring-roo/bin
>   export PATH

PATH variable

> my-Name-3:~ myUsr$ echo $PATH
>       /sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/Users/myUsr/spring-roo/bin

In this path (/Users/myUsr/spring-roo/bin), there is `roo.sh`

But then, I can not run the command `roo` as it is supposed to be.

Comment: Is there an executable `roo` in /Users/myUsr/spring-roo/bin? Where did you try the commands listed? Commands seem reasonable; if you issue these in a terminal window and then issue `roo` it should work. What does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: Yes, in that dir there is roo.sh.  when I type echo $PATH:   my-Name-3:~ myUsr$ echo $PATH
/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/Users/myUsr/spring-roo/bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to be able to run a command `roo` (no `.sh`), when all you have is `roo.sh`. Run `roo.sh` instead. There is no magic dropping of extensions in Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the directory where the root.sh is ? Just give a try by being in that directory to run the shell script. Also check the permissions of the file.

Comment: Yes, no problem of permission, if I run ./roo.sh in that directory, works without any problem